# divide vertex into two

Tags: bevel

Is there some quick way to "divide" (bevel) one vertex inside a geometry into two making a edge between them like on the picture?
[image]

Comment: imho not so quick, you could use rip (V) then slide (shift V) along an edge, then recontruct missing faces (F) and then dissolve two edges...

Answer (score 1):

In this case beveling vertex won't really help as it will create Ngon with too many sides:

[image: screnshot-beveling-nightmare]

While it's possible to fix that Ngon to desired face later it can be cumbersome as original vertices position won't be the case any more.
Instead you can try [Rip tool](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/vertices.html) to detach some faces, fill new one and split it. Then dissolve unnecessary geometry. Note though that both procedures - beveling and merging vs ripping and dissolving - take nearly the same amount of effort.

Select vertex where edges are connecting (by the way too many edges are joining at one point there). Then press <kbd>V</kbd> to execute Rip tool. Your mouse cursor will affect which part is being ripped, in the case below mouse cursor was to the left top so to rip left faces.

[image: screenshot-ripping]

Fill a new face there and split it at the vertices in the middle with *Connect Vertex Path* tool (<kbd>J</kbd>); select vertices first and then execute the tool. It will split the face into 2 triangles.

Then merge unncessary vertex and dissolve edges which are no longer needed.

[image: screenshot-process]

The result isn't clean, it's more of a middle position between further retopology.